# why I am not able to set the GpsLongitude correctly to exif?

Tags: c++, gps, exif

I have this code:

```
PropertyItem propertyItem;
int degree = 10, minutes = 10, second = 10;
unsigned long ulExifCoordFormat[6] = {degree, 1, minutes, 1, second, 1};
propertyItem.id = PropertyTagGpsLongitude;
propertyItem.type=PropertyTagTypeRational;
propertyItem.length = sizeof( unsigned long ) * 6;
propertyItem.value =ulExifCoordFormat;
bitmap->Setproperty(&propertyItem);
```

This code should set the `Longitude to 10,10,10,` but it set it to some wrong values.

Similar code that  have for setting Latitude works fine:

```
PropertyItem propertyItem;
int degree = 20, minutes = 20, second = 20;
unsigned long ulExifCoordFormat[6] = {degree, 1, minutes, 1, second, 1};
propertyItem.id = PropertyTagGpsLatitude;
propertyItem.type=PropertyTagTypeRational;
propertyItem.length = sizeof( unsigned long ) * 6;
propertyItem.value =ulExifCoordFormat;
bitmap->Setproperty(&propertyItem);
```

The code is based on this MSDN document:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533832(v=vs.85).aspx

and this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20c004d6-1815-42da-aa04-03b4a895bef6/using-gdi-image-class-to-store-gps-information?forum=vcgeneral

### Edit 1

Just noted that it depends which one I set first. The first one set correctly and the second one is not correct. Apparently I can only add one item with this function. How can I set several items at the same time?